# incredible thing in Smarty 3

Tags: php, smarty

I wrote small plugin for smarty 3 to allocate my files in case of theme options. It work fine all the time, but i choose new template for new project. And discover something mad!

```
{block name="css_load"}
        <link href="{asset file='plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="{asset file='plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css'}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
{/block}
```

Normal code isn't it? But it throw exception:

```
Syntax error in template "\www\themes\default\base.tpl"  on line 12 "<link href="{asset file='plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">"  - Unexpected "'plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'", expected one of: "identifier"
```

And how to fix it? Just add an extra "s" in path string like this:

```
{block name="css_load"}
        <link href="{asset file='plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.csss'}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="{asset file='plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css'}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
{/block}
```

And it will work fine without exception!

WHAT IS THAT?!

Smarty version 3.1.15

Template: metronic 1.4

Comment: What I'd like to know is what made you think of adding a `s` in the first place?

Comment: You should check what is happening inside the asset plugin. And Smarty can make strange things if you copy an older template file. (It won't recompile it if the related template_c file is newer.)

Comment: Probably it's not the 's', it's that the file doesn't exist